# Bitmap issue in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android

I wrote a method to change Bitmap from camera shot :

```
public Bitmap bitmapChange(Bitmap bm) {
    /* get original image size */
    int w = bm.getWidth();
    int h = bm.getHeight();

    /* check the image's orientation */
    float scale = w / h;

    if(scale < 1) { 

        /* if the orientation is portrait then scaled and show on the screen*/
        float scaleWidth = (float) 90 / (float) w;
        float scaleHeight = (float) 130 / (float) h;
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
        return rotatedBMP;

    } else {

        /* if the orientation is landscape then rotate 90 */
        float scaleWidth = (float) 130 / (float) w;
        float scaleHeight = (float) 90 / (float) h;
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        mtx.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
        return rotatedBMP;
    }
}
```

It works fine in another Android device, even Galaxy Nexus but in Samsung Galaxy S3, the scaled image doesn't show on screen.

I tried to mark the `bitmapChange` method , let it show the original size Bitmap on screen but S3 also show nothing on screen.

The information of variables in eclipse is [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90416799/s3_bitmap_info.png).
The information of sony xperia is [here](http://ppt.cc/w03U).

xperia and other device is working fine.

Edit:

I got some Strange log in LogCat,

when i take a picture the LogCat show some message:

[here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90416799/log.png)

I never use video...

why video is started??

Comment: don't focus on the reason why i have to scale the bitmap, it is a complicated story that i don't want to say it. Lets focus on why S3 can't show the image on ImageView, the mHight and mWidth are also -1 in S3 and xperia, but why xperia can work fine, even another device..., just S3 failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched around and it seems there might be two possible reasons:

1) S3 has memory problems. Check out [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170805/galaxy-s-3-memory-problems) The S3 gives problems even when scaling images!

**Solution-** The solution is to make the bitmap conversion more *memory-friendly* as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999204/android-gridview-crashes-on-galaxy-3)

---

2) Samsung phones set the EXIF orientation tag, rather than rotating individual pixels

**Solution-** Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023696/setrotation90-to-take-picture-in-portrait-mode-does-not-work-on-samsung-device)

Comment: In my case, Samsung Galaxy Nexsus is work fine...just S3 can't show image, and i found some strange message in LogCat, did someone know why the video function is triggered when i want to take picture?